# Execute git pull command over ssh on window server hangs forever

Tags: git, ssh, windows-server-2012, git-pull

I have a windows server 2012 with bitvise ssh server installed on it, beside git and git bash, I have set up a virtual user and git it full permission over a folder contains a git repository (Let's call it GR).
Now when I open the server via remove desktop connection and open GR folder using cmd and perform `git pull` everything works as expected and I get the latest commits. but When I connect to the server via ssh client and change the directory `cd` to GR folder and perform `git pull` the execution hangs forever and it's not working.
I tried to change bitvise to PowerShell but I got the same result, so anyone could help me on how am I going to run `git pull` command over ssh on windows server.

Note: I change the ssh default port for windows server `bitvise` but It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue as follows:

- Execute GIT_TRACE=1 which give me where the git command is stuck `19:07:59.137016 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager get`
- Now I knew that the ssh doesn't have access for window credential manager, so I need a way to provide the credentials inside git pull command, as I'm using GitLab I used `git clone https://username:token@gitlab.com/user/repo.git`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question. I had the exact same problem and got around it by providing full credentials like `git pull http://user:pass@domain:port/repo.git`. Interestingly enough, when the target machine is Windows  10, no such problem exists in my case. Maybe git was not set up exactly the same way, I will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened all the required ports on the server? Firewall traffic? you can try execute `git pull --trace-ascii`

This should give you some more overview hopefully.

Comment: The command is GIT_TRACE=1 git pull, and thanks a lot for the clue (Tracing), I managed to find the true solution for this issue @shaolin